# PHP foreach - Do something after every third element

Tags: php

I'm trying to place some AD's after every third element but it still doesn't work like I want it. Thats why I've created a little code snipped that reflecs my situation with an easy php array.

```
   <?php 

$arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
$counter = 1;
foreach($arr as $a){
    echo "$a \n";
    if( $counter%3==0){
        echo "something awesome\n";
    }
    $counter++;
}
```

This returns that:

```
1
2
3
something awesome
4
5
6
something awesome
7
8
9
something awesome

But I only want it 2x - like:

1
2
3
something awesome
4
5
6
something awesome
7
8
9
```

2x "something awesome" would be better than 3x times but I couln't make it at all.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Classic fizzbuzz question here...

Comment: Counting is difficult, everybody knows that. Initialize `$counter` with `1` and increment it (instead of decrementing it). This is how I learned to count a while ago.

Comment: ha... yeah maybe.. my brain is like afk right now

Comment: Simple assignment, can't find answer, decides to dump on SO instead of having a coffee, a good night of sleep ([or a beginner's course](https://blog.codinghorror.com/why-cant-programmers-program/)).   -.-

Comment: well I've got it to work with 3x something awesome. But 2x didn't worked

Answer (score 1):

Since everybody is eager to show they can count, here is my attempt:

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
foreach ($arr as $k => $a){
    if ($k && $k % 3 == 0) {
        echo "something awesome\n";
    }
    echo "$a \n";
}
```

Sorry about removing the `$counter` variable. It was useless.

Answer (score 1):

When using `foreach()` you can use `$key` and `$value` of the array.

```
<?php 

$arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

$counter = count($arr);

foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    echo $value . '<br>';

    if($key % 3 == 2 && $key+1 < $counter ){
        echo "something awesome<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: there isn't an associative array. The output of this is not as requested.

Comment: @ADyson all PHP arrays are associative. When the keys are not specified, PHP uses [numeric consecutive keys starting with `0`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying).

Comment: @ADyson please just try the code I've posted before you blame it. Except of ` - $key` I get the exact output as desired. Go to this site: http://www.writephponline.com/ paste my code, click on "Run Code" see the result...

Comment: I did, it produces `1 - 0
2 - 1
3 - 2
something awesome
4 - 3
5 - 4
6 - 5
something awesome
7 - 6
8 - 7
9 - 8` which is not as requested.

Comment: @ADyson I left the key in the output to show / teach something. Now I've removed it for you (big time facepalm)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do here is make use of the modulus % operator, please see comment below.

```
<?php

$arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

foreach($arr as $a)
{
    echo "$a\n";
    if($a % 3 == 0) // If $a divided by 3 leaves no remainder 
    {
        echo "something awesome\n";
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do it. Possibly not the most elegant way but it works:

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
$counter = 1;
$overallCount = 1;
foreach($arr as $a){
    echo "$a \n";
    if( $counter == 3 && $overallCount < count($arr)){
        echo "something awesome\n";
        $counter = 0;
    }
    $counter++;
    $overallCount++;
}
```